# Why the one validation score is lower than the other sections of cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I was working on RandomForestClassifier and doing hyperparameter tuning. But something caught my attention. I always get a lower validation value in the 2nd part of Cross Validation. Here is the code:

```
model6 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 200,
                            max_depth = 10,
                            min_samples_leaf = 2,
                            min_samples_split = 2)



 cross_val_score(model6,
            X_train,
            y_train,
            cv = 5,
            scoring = 'accuracy')

 array([0.87755102, 0.83673469, 0.85416667, 0.91666667, 0.875     ])
```

As you see the second section is lower than the others. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

This problem also might be related to the seeding of the random number generator (RNG). Typically, your RNG spits out a sequence of pseudo-random numbers, meaning, that they look random but there might be, e.g., some repetition at some point. The random number seed tells the RNG where to start in this very long sequence of (pseudo) random numbers. In other words, if you always "seed" the RNG with the same integer value, then you always get a reproducible sequence of random numbers. THis is useful for reproducing of results and for debugging.

E.g. in numpy, if you set the seed as

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)
print(np.random.rand())

np.random.seed(10)
print(np.random.rand())
```

you will get two times the same number. If you use `np.random.seed(None)` (or `np.random.seed()`) you always will get  different random numbers.

It is important to note that the RNGs of numpy and, e.g., pytorch need both to be initialized/seeded.

Comment: After your comment i splitted data with random_state from 1 until 10. And the highest validation score mean has come with random_state = 8.

`array([0.95918367, 0.81632653, 0.91666667, 0.91666667, 0.85416667])`

But still second section is the lower one.

Comment: I think it ain't about modelling it's about data processing. Or data's structure.

Comment: I think it would tremendously increase your chance for getting a helpful reply if you would post a piece of code in the spirit of a minimal working example...

Comment: I posted the code as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe data is not shuffled properly. Try to shuffle it explicitly before cross_val_score() is called. What is your dataset?

Comment: I shuffled data with `data.sample(frac = 1)`. Also my data is heart disease dataset.

Comment: Also, make sure that you didn't fix the seeding of the random number generator. A piece of complete but minimal code would be quite helpful to give some proper advice.

Comment: That is the another subject which i don't understand. Just because of it i don't use any random seed for generators. Because when i use i always take another validation score. Higher or lower.

Comment: since the explanation is a bit longer and needed code formatting I added an answer which should explain these things. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is the code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                                    y,
                                                    test_size = 0.2)

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 200,
                               max_depth = 10,
                               min_samples_leaf = 2,
                               min_samples_split = 2,
                               random_state = 8)

cross_val_score(model,
                X_train,
                y_train,
                cv = 5,
                scoring = 'accuracy').mean()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).